# $R[t]/\langle tf-g\rangle\cong R[\frac{g}{f}]$ iff $\langle tg-f\rangle$ is a prime ideal in $R[t]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let us assume $R$ is a domain and $f,g \in R$ with $f \neq 0$. prove that $R[t]/\langle tf-g\rangle\cong R[\frac{g}{f}]$ iff $\langle tg-f\rangle$ is a prime ideal in $R[t]$.

The only idea I have for this problem is to show that if $\langle tf-g\rangle$ is prime ideal in $R[t]$ if $\frac{g}{f}$ isn't integrable over $R[t]$. But I apart from this I don't have any solid lead to solve this problem. It will be great if you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by integrable?

Answer (score 1):

As the $R[g/f]$ is a domain, clearly the isomorphism implies $(tf - g)$ is prime.

Now Consider the natural map from $R[t]$ to $R[g/f]$ sending $t$ to $g/f$. If $F$ lies in this kernel, then by passing to the field fractions $K$ of $R$ we see that $tf-g \mid F$ in $K[t]$. If $tf - g$ is prime, this will imply $tf - g \mid F$ in $R[t]$.